# How to access hadoop remotely

Tags: hadoop, openstack

I have installed `Hadoop` on open-stack `CentOS` guest VM. I am able to open the site

```
(From 192.168.0.10, VM-1)
http://localhost:50070
http://192.168.0.10:50070
```

But not able to access the same from a remote machine (My Computer).

```
http://210.84.35.1:50070
```

Here is my network diagram

```
                                                          Open-Stack
                               ---------------------------------------------------------------                                
                               |                                                             |
                               |   [Remote Network]          [Open-Stack-VM Network]         |
                               |                                                             |
                               |                   |           |192.168.0.10                 | 
                               |  210.84.35.0/24   |           |____________ [CentOS VM-1]   | 
[My-Computer] ----(Internet)---|--- _______________|___________|                             | 
                               |                   |           |192.168.0.11                 | 
                               |                   |           |____________ [CentOS VM-2]   |
                               |-------------------|-----------|-----------------------------
```

Comment: Have you tried to ping `210.84.35.1` ? Should not ur IP be `210.84.35.10`!